# datatable.colReorder is undefined

Tags: javascript, datatable

I need to change column order after draw. Here is what I do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $datatable = $('.dataTable').DataTable();
    $datatable.on( 'draw', function () {
        console.log( "DONE" );
        $datatable.colReorder.move( 4, 2 );
    } );
});
```

and output is following

```
 DONE view:1972:21
 TypeError: $datatable.colReorder is undefined
```

Comment: Which DataTable version are you using?

Comment: Have you defined colReorder config inside datatable?
`colReorder: true`


Can you try this -

 var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    colReorder: true
} );

Comment: @palaѕн  version:1.10.19

Comment: @Tethys0 its already inited

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://live.datatables.net/jozumupa/40/edit

Comment: @palaѕн I didn't realize that is plugin and need to load it too. When loaded I get now this:  this.context[0]._colReorder is undefineddataTables.colReorder.js:1352:3. And can't enable it through $datatable.colReorder.enable( true ); says .colReorder is undefined

Comment: Is the demo I had shared seems working?

Comment: @palaѕн by that link yes :) But on my side errors which I sent in my previous comment

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here with the js files you are using atm and see if you can reproduce the exact same issue again. No need to add large HTML markup for the table, just add few rows for demo purpose.